# pcl_visualization cannot detect .h file

Tags: ros, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello all,

I am trying to visualize point cloud information, using the pcl_visualization package from perception_pcl_addons. following is ithe relevant part of the code i am using:

```
#include <pcl_visualization slash cloud_viewer.h>

void depth_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 &cloud2_msg)
{

    std::string filename="test_pcd.pcd";

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> cloud_t_msg;

    pcl::fromROSMsg(cloud2_msg,cloud_t_msg);

    pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII(filename,cloud_t_msg);

    pcl_visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Simple Cloud Viewer");

    viewer.showCloud(cloud);

    while (!viewer.wasStopped())
    {
    }

}
```

(there's a long list of attached files that i'm not mentioning)

here's the error i get - it cannot find cloud_viewer.h eventhough i have confirmed it exists at the proper location in my filesystem.

```
/home/samarth/kinect_listener/src/listener.cpp:20:44: error: pcl_visualization/cloud_viewer.h: No such file or directory

/home/samarth/kinect_listener/src/listener.cpp: In function ‘void depth_cb(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&)’:

/home/samarth/kinect_listener/src/listener.cpp:69: error: ‘pcl_visualization’ has not been declared

/home/samarth/kinect_listener/src/listener.cpp:69: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘viewer’

/home/samarth/kinect_listener/src/listener.cpp:70: error: ‘viewer’ was not declared in this scope

make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/src/listener.o] Error 1

make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/samarth/kinect_listener/build'

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/listener.dir/all] Error 2

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/samarth/kinect_listener/build'

make[1]: *** [all] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/samarth/kinect_listener/build'

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

PS - my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable is suitably set. so no problem there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10429/pcl_visualization-cannot-detect-.h-file/) by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-29**:
you can use the edit button to fix your posts, and update them with more information too.

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-29**:
ok, will do that in future, thanks!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-06-29**:
You can make code appear as code by indenting it using 4 spaces.

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-28**:
i dunno how the include line got edited by itself, but its #include <pcl_visualization/cloud_viewer.h>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you add perception_pcl_addons to the package dependency?

---

Originally posted by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) with karma: 311 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfexceltide](https://answers.ros.org/users/687/surfexceltide/) on 2011-06-29**:
ok, gotcha! that did the trick! :)